# Area51 Says Music.SE Still in Beta

Tags: support, area51, graduation

[On Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4059/musical-practice-and-performance), it still says we are in public beta.  The day count is also still going up.  Is this a glitch?

Comment: Maybe the Area 51 is a bit slow on the update

Comment: I believe that this is a bug in Area51, not here.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266277/are-graduating-sites-considered-launched

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't change (as of now) until our design is complete have the as that is when we are "fully graduated". We've started the process, but we're not done yet. Other SE that have started graduation also have not been listed as graduated like Code Review, Anime, and Blender.